# Python Flask запуск сервера без порта в url

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Как сделать так, чтобы в url не было порта?

```
import os
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return redirect(url_for('foo'))

@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    return 'Hello Foo!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Запускается по адресу

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/foo
```

А мне бы хотелось

```
http://127.0.0.1/foo
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вместо порта 5000 использовать порт "по умолчанию", то есть 80

Comment: Только вот делать так не надо, потому что встроенный flask-сервер предназначен только для тестирования, а не для реальной работы

Comment: Пишет,что порт уже используется. Может как-то через редирект можно?

Comment: Кем используется?

Comment: tcp    LISTEN  0       128                       *:80                   *:*      users:(("httpd",pid=6196,fd=4),("httpd",pid=5929,fd=4),("httpd",pid=5928,fd=4),("httpd",pid=5927,fd=4),("httpd",pid=1325,fd=4))

Comment: Ну вот значит в настройках этого самого httpd и настройте проксирование на порт 5000, наверное?

Comment: Хорошо. Попробую. А все же, если через редирект возможно?

Comment: Непонятно при чём тут редирект, он сможет лишь вывалить порт 5000 в адрес

Comment: Ну и повторюсь ещё раз, не надо делать никаких редиректов и никаких проксирований на встроенный flask-сервер, потому что он предназначен только для тестирования, а не для реальной работы

Comment: Понял Вас. Благодарю